# Matrix template of template

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I'm trying to implement a simple Matrix class template 
I would like to instantiate it like Matrix(data1 , .. , dataN) 
basically I thought to define a template class that takes the 2 unsigned int as template parameter , and using the initialisation list to deduce the type of the data containing right now I wrote this simple start :

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
class Matrix {

    public:

    template<typename ...T>   
       constexpr Matrix<N,M>(T ... args ) noexcept 
           : data{std::forward<T>(args)... } 
           {
               static_assert(sizeof...(args) <= N*M, "Insufficent element for a Matrix " );

           } 

    const auto getData()const { return data; }


    private:

    template<typename T>
    std::valarray<T> data ;  
};
```

but i got a error ..

> error: data member ‘data’ cannot be a member template
>        std::valarray data ;

so what do you think about ? there is a way to deduce the type of the Matrix 
by her initialisation (parameter passed to the constructor) and use this time 
along all class definition ?

Comment: I dont know if member variables can be templated in C++14 or beyond, but anyhow why is `T` not a parameter for the whole class?

Comment: I would expect `typename T` to be the first (or last) template argument of the class.

Comment: because I would use Matrix<N,M> for instantiate these .. so the class template parameter should be <size_t , size_t> ... where I can insert the T ?? deducing what ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to *defer* the `template <typename T>` to the constructor. The matrix needs to know what `T` it is going to store before the constructor is called, otherwise it would be impossible to calculate the size of the matrix object. So, you'll have to declare the class like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
class Matrix
{
public:
    // Constructors and stuff

private:
    std::valarray<T> data ;  
};
```

*(note: there is no `size_t` type in C++, but there is `std::size_t`)*

The non-possibility of deducing this `T` is an annoying thing. People used to write wrappers like [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair), [`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple), and so on, relying on the ability of functions to derive their arguments' types.

The upcoming [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) standard has the feature you want, called [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). It even allows one to guide the deduction process, like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array
{
    T data[N];

    template <typename ... X>
    array (X ... x)
        : data{x...}
    { }
};

template <typename ... X>
array(X ...) -> array<std::common_type_t<X...>, sizeof...(X)>;
```

Unfortunatelly, in your case it is impossible to derive `N` and `M`, so you'll have to change the constructor signature in order to use this feature.

Comment: sorry I don't understand ... in which way ?

Comment: @MarcoGhiani: just make constructor non-templated because by lisyarus suggestion you'll already have `T` as your class template parameter. Also now `data` will be a regular member, not templated

Comment: no i didn't ... I have `template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M > `